# Trigger insert if update matches conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to provoke MySQL to run INSERT instead of UPDATE if it meets certain conditions.. Consider this simple table with `id, user_id` and couple other simple fields. id is a primary autoincrement. And then someone runs update and tries to change user_id

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `mytable` BEFORE UPDATE ON `mytable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.user_id != NEW.user_id THEN
    SET NEW.id = NULL;
  END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Now the problem is, that of course it doesn't work because you can't run UPDATE with the primary key set to NULL (I was hoping to trigger INSERT if NULL is provided for primary key value).

Initially i thought i could just run another insert here, and put some SIGNAL or other type of breaking the current update.. And by typing all the fields and values into insert, but i want to be sure the NEW object is inserted no matter how many fields there are inside, i only need `id` to be autoincremented.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to get the next ID of the autoincrement on the update command?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I would like mysql to deal with autoincrements, and just focus on properly inserting what is in NEW, and stopping update

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not understanding it right because of my poor english. If I understood it right you want to insert a row when you run a update command. If that is what you want, **you can't** (or shouldn't)! Best you can do is to avoid something to update throwing some error signal. MySql will deal with autoincrement just for insert commands, AFAIK.

Comment: @JorgeCampos i see, i was afraid of that....

Comment: Why not step back and ponder the schema (like show this: `show create table mytable` <----- the output of that) and what statement got you here in the first place. You are puttng the horse in front of the cart by coming in talking about the trigger first.

Comment: You can use "replace into" syntax instead of writing triggers.

Comment: @Msfvtp it's another [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) at the moment

Comment: @Drew It was only a hint. :)

Comment: @Msfvtp caution with replace [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZxDAumH.jpg) from the man page